# Is it possible to have random number chain relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

The real problem is like this.There are two equations executing in parallel. Can anybody help ?

Ex: There are four random numbers 5 7 2 and 4. These numbers are related through a chain of relations and a initial value I=20. Scenario is to create a chain of mathematical relation of these random numbers and output as a response. On retrieval, one should get all these numbers.

1> Calculation:

Step1:`20 + 5 = 25` `20 - 5 = 15`

Step2:`25 + 7 = 32` `15 - 7 = 8`

Step3:`32 + 2 = 34` `8 - 2 = 6`

Step4:`34 + 4 = 38` `6 - 4 = 2`

Last numbers 38 and 2 are given.

2> Retrieval(Should get all the values 4,2,7,5): We have known only 38 and 2 as a result from Calculation step. problem is having 38 and 2, possible to get 34 and 6 ? How to solve the following formula and get exact value of x and y?

`x + a = 38`

`y - a = 2`

Comment: You're adding a bunch of stuff to $I$ to get $38$, and subtracting the same bunch of stuff from $I$ to get $2$.  That is, $I+x=38$ and $I-x=2$, where $x=5+7+2+4$ (the sum of your four random numbers).  From this you can deduce that $I=20$ and that $x=18$, but that's it... there's no way to break $x$ back into its components.